# How can i save changes made to the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have the following action for Edit,

In the view i have the following code

```
<form asp-action="Edit" class="form-horizontal">
   <input type="text" asp-for="Code" value="@Model.Code" class="form-control" />
   <button class="btn btn-success Product-edit-button" role="button">Save</button>
</form>
```

How can i save changes to Database on button click?

Here is what i tried, edit model look like

```
public async Task<IActionResult> editModel(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var ProductList = (await ProductService.GetProducts()).ToList();

            var Product = ProductList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == id);

            if (Product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(Product);
        }
```

Edit Action looks like as follow

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(ProductEditModel editModel)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var ProductList = (await ProductService.GetProducts()).ToList();
            var Product = ProductList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == id);
            if (Product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            Product.Code = editModel.Code;
            ProductService.EditProduct(Product);

            return View(Product);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another action that accept POST request and send edited data to it.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(ProductEditModel editModel)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }    
            var ProductList = (await ProductService.GetProducts()).ToList();    
            var Product = ProductList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID ==editModel.Id);    
            if (Product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }  
          Product.Code=editModel.Code;
          ProductService.EditProduct(Product);

            return View(Product);
        }
```

The Model :

```
public class ProductEditModel {
public int Id {get;set;}
public string code{get; set;}
}
```

The View:

```html
 <form asp-action="Edit" class="form-horizontal">
       <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" value="@Model.Id" class="form-control" />
        <input type="text" asp-for="Code" value="@Model.Code" class="form-control" />
       <button class="btn btn-success Product-edit-button" role="button">Save</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you How can i pass `id , this line gives me error id doesnt exist in current context var Project = ProjectList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == id);`? and what is  `ProductService.EditProduct(Product);`and `ProjectEditModel`

Comment: Mike can you show me how `ProjectEditModel` Action look like? Sorry i am bit confused

Comment: The ProjectEditModel  is a class.  I think the confusing is create a new action in your Controller. I will update the code in some minutes.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I want to see how the other Action look like

Comment: I see you update the question. That is correct . just rename the editModel action to Edit.

Comment: What about `ProductService.EditProduct(Product);` do i have to create EditProduct List? also id still doesnt ecist in the current context

Comment: I suppose  you have an EditProduct in your ProductService to update the product.

Comment: What is the parameter for `EditProduct` in ProductService  ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working demo like below:

1.Model:

```
public class ProductEditModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

2.View(Edit.cshtml):

```
@model ProductEditModel
<h4>ProductEditModel</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="ID" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Code" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Code" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Code" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

3.Controller:

```
public class ProductEditModelsController : Controller
{
    private readonly YourContext _context;

    public ProductEditModelsController(YourContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    // GET: ProductEditModels/Edit/5
    //display edit view
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var productEditModel = await _context.ProductEditModel.FindAsync(id);
        if (productEditModel == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(productEditModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(ProductEditModel productEditModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Update(productEditModel);//update model
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();//save to database
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(productEditModel);
    }
}
```

4.DbContext:

```
public class YourContext: DbContext
{
    public YourContext(DbContextOptions<YourContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<ProductEditModel> ProductEditModel { get; set; }
}
```

5.Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{     
    //...  
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    services.AddDbContext<YourContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourConnnection"))); //connect to sql server
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   //...      
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Privacy}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Result:
[image]
**Update:**

1.Index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProductEditModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Code)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

2.Index action in controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.ProductEditModel.ToListAsync());
}
```

If you do not understand successfully,please learn the mvc tutorial below first.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Actually,I share the code.Did you mean you want the whole code for CRUD?

Comment: Hi,please check my answer.If still have problems,please learn mvc tutorial first:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio